# Как сделать срез элементов с индексами и отсортировать

Tags: golang

У меня есть массив [10, 65, 21, 19, 43]

```
array := []int{10, 65, 21, 19, 43}
```

Мне нужно сделать массив вида (value, index): [[10, 0], [65, 1], [21, 2], [19, 3], [43, 4]]
По сути, как в Python через enumerate: `[(v, i) for v, i in enumerate(array)]`

А потом, также как в Python отсортировать его: по value. Можно просто написать `array.sort()`

Как также сделать в Golang? Не понимаю, как добавить слайс в слайс и, к тому же, отсортировать по первому значению, дошел только до функции range, но он раскрывает слайс, что логично. Если не раскрывать, то кидает ошибку:

```
nums := []int{10, 65, 21, 19, 43}   
data := make([]int, 5)
for index, value := range nums {
    data = append(data, []int{index, value}...)
}
return data
```

Comment: Вам нужно создавать не просто массив, а массив массивов - data := make([][]int, len(nums)) для начала

Comment: @DanielProtopopov благодарю, действительно, нужно было указать `[][]int`. Не подскажете, как отсортировать срез по первому элементу? То есть отсортировать `[[3, 0], [2, 1], [1, 2]]`, чтобы на выходе было `[[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Пример](https://go.dev/play/p/dtkqUXCnIFn) решения:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Matrix [][]int

func main() {
    data := []int{10, 65, 21, 19, 43}
    var matrix [][]int
    for index, value := range data {
        matrix = append(matrix, []int{value, index})
    }
    sort.SliceStable(matrix, func(i, j int) bool {
        return matrix[i][0] < matrix[j][0]
    })

    fmt.Println(matrix)
}
```

Результат:
[[10 0] [19 3] [21 2] [43 4] [65 1]]

Program exited.